# ngDialog width and overlay

Tags: css, angularjs, dialog

Im using Ionic framework.
By default, running this code:

```
$scope.dialog = ngDialog.open(
{
template: 'popup.html'
, className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
, controller: 'MyCtrl'
);
```

opens a popup whose overlay takes up all the width of the screen.
Also the width of the dialog is 100%.

I want the dialog to take up about 80% of the screen.
Adding a custom class like this:

```
, className: 'ngdialog-theme-default mycustomdialog'

.mycustomdialog{width:80%}
```

makes the dialog to be 80% of the screen. The problem is that the overlay also becomes 80% of the screen.
Which I think is not that nice. Am I doing something wrong or there is a way to make the overlay continue taking up 100% while dialog is 80%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `.ngdialog-content` width `80%` based on the added class.

**Do this:**

```
.ngdialog.mycustomdialog .ngdialog-content{
    width:80%;
}
```